# ¿Cómo debe ser el texto del sms para abrir directamente una aplicación de mapas?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gps, sms

Hola ante todo agradecer por la ayuda que me puedan dar. Deseo que al enviar un sms desde mi aplicación Android con las coordenadas de un lugar (latitud y longitud) de que forma tendría que ponerlo en el cuerpo del sms para que el receptor del sms al pulsar sobre dicho texto se le abra OsmAnd o MAPS.ME u otra APK con las coordenas enviadas en el sms.

Comment: Por favor realiza el [tour] del sitio para que conozcas su funcionamiento. Modifica tu pregunta en base a el documento [ask], agrega lo que has tratado o investigado, con esto tendrás mejores respuestas, saludos.

Comment: para navegadores con que mandes el link. Si existe una app y se detecta, se derivará con una pregunta al usuario. ej. https://maps.google.com/?q=19.937696,-99.222336